# Почему не запускается приложение timeshift для бэкапа?

Tags: ubuntu

Делаю бэкапы с помощью timeshift, но не запускается графический интерфейс программы. Иконочка программы мелькает и тухнет. Саму прогу можно запустить только из терминала с правами рут. 
Кто знает как решить эту проблему?

Comment: В параметрах ярлыка сделать запуск с правами рут.

Comment: Нельзя изменить права, потому что не вы являетесь владельцем. Владелец файла рут. Так может мне поменять владельца, то есть себя?